# Kodaira's Lemma and first chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Kodaira's lemma states the following: Let $L$ be a nef and big line bundle on a complex manifold $X$. There there exists an effective divisor $E$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $c_1(L) - \varepsilon c_1(L_{E}) > 0$ for all $\varepsilon \in (0, \delta]$, where $L_{E}$ is the line bundle associated with $E$.

I was reading about the following conclusions:

On a Kahler manifold $X$ with a big and nef class $\Omega$, there exists a number $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small and an effective divisor $[E]$, such that $\Omega - \varepsilon c_1([E]) > 0$. Let $S_{E}$ be defining section of $E$ and $h_{E}$ a smooth hermitian metric on $L_{E}$, then one have a Kahler metric $\theta + \varepsilon i \partial \bar \partial \log h_{E}$.

I have following questions:

1). what does $\log h_{E}$ mean? It is my understanding that the first chern class of a line bundle is represented by $\log |S|_{h_{E}}^2$ where $S$ is a nonvanishing section of $L_{E}$.

2). What does the statement have to do with the defining section of $E$?

Comment: Can you add the source from which you are reading? It makes it easier for potential answerers to cross-check, see if there are any assumptions/simplifications earlier in the text, etc.